# User image display on fiori launchpad and me area

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

How to show user image in `sap fiori 2.0` launchpad in user and me area?

Answer (score 0):

In the [official docu](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nw751abap/7.51.0/en-US/27/834b1aacf344f38910686d8fb0eb0a/frameset.htm) it says:
“At the top of the Me Area, you can see: Your user name and profile image.
Note:
Your photo appears only if SAP Jam integration is enabled and if your photo is defined in the SAP Jam landscape.”

You also have to enable “Show profile picture on the FLP and mobile apps” in the “Profile Picture Settings” via the “Settings” in the “Me Area”.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually I am talking about fiori 2.0 in this architecture has been chnaged and sap jam is no more used. Please suggest for the said version.

Comment: Hi All, I have followed below url and implemented this requirement. I am not able to see image still.If any one is have done that please help to fix this issue. Let me know if you need my code.      URL : https://blogs.sap.com/2016/12/02/custom-user-image-in-fiori-2.0/